# Is liquibase eclipse plugin no longer available

Tags: liquibase

Tried to install the eclipse liquibase plugin from here:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/liquibase-eclipse-plugin

and I get:

No repository found at http://liquibase-eclipse-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/com.svcdelivery.liquibase.eclipse.site/.

Sure enough that is not a valid URL.

Comment: Can you try following? (Open Eclipse > Help > Eclipse Market > Search for Liquibase > Click on Install)

Comment: Rakmo - did that, get the same error as going to the marketplace web site.

Comment: From this link https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/liquibase-eclipse-plugin, it looks like they have recently updated the version. I would recommend to add your comment in the link so that eclipse market community will take some action. I hope it helps.